Why the Sun has a higher temperature than humans?
Why the Sun has a higher temperature than humans if the energy/gramme of matter ratio of humans is greater than that of the Sun?

The thermal energy per gram of matter of the Sun is definitely higher than of humans, being between 6000K and 15000000K depending on where in the Sun.
What you are probably thinking of is the fact that humans put out more power per unit volume than the Sun, described here.
The reason for that is, even though the matter of the Sun has a lot more thermal energy per unit volume, the Sun is very large, and is a sphere, meaning that the Sun has a very low surface area to volume ratio. Energy can only escape from the surface, so there is so much energy inside the Sun that cannot escape. Humans, being small, have vastly more surface area per unit volume relative to their size, that the average cubic centimeter of human puts out more energy than the average cubic centimeter of Sun, because most cubic centimeters of the Sun are buried down where energy cannot escape.
To see the math behind that, the average human has a volume of 62 liters and puts out about 100 watts of power, in the form of body heat and infrared radiation lost to the environment, or about 1.6 watts per liter. The Sun puts out 3.85*10^26 watts, but has a volume of about 1.4*10^30 liters, so about 0.000275 watts per liter of material on average, which is much less power per average liter.
